# Keeping only certain fields on a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

I have a couple of CSV files which have a lot of fields, but I only need to keep a few of them, so I wanted to get rid of the extra data before importing them.

I tought of running:

```
perl -i.bak -F, -ane 'BEGIN {$,=","} print @F[3..6], @F[9..12]' file.csv
```

Although text fields are quoted, some fields contain commas and this simple solution does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV). It handles fields containing the delimiter, among many other nice features.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
    eol => $/,
    always_quote => 1
}) or die 'Cannot use CSV: ' . Text::CSV->error_diag();

my $file = 'input.csv';
my $backup = "$file.bak";
copy $file, $backup or die "Copy failed: $!";

open my $in_fh, '<', $backup or die "$backup: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $file or die "$file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in_fh)) {
    my @wanted = @$row[3..6,9..12];
    $csv->print($out_fh, \@wanted);
}

close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! One last thing, I need to concatenate fields 3 and 4, while running `sprintf ('%02d', @$row[4])`, how can I do this?

Comment: @user1608941: That should be `$row->[4]`, and are you aware that's field 5 because the indexing starts at zero?

Comment: @user1608941 Add something like `splice @wanted, 0, 2, sprintf('%s%02d', @wanted[0..1]);` after the `my @wanted ...` line. As Borodin said, be aware that fields are indexed from 0, so `$row->[4]` is actually the *fifth* field in your CSV, not the fourth.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant 5 :) This worked out great, thank you all for your help!